# Print 2d String array by column

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing a school project and I need to print the array by amount spent (descending). The problem is that I got nulls inside it by joining 5 arrays into one and having to gather the information inside a for loop so I had to declare the array at the top of my code.

So my code is something like this:

```
                             ⇩

                   Entry | Amount | Category     | Payment | Date

String array[][]={  {"5", "22,2", "car payment", "visa", "21/04/2016"},
                    {"1", "44,4", "shop", "cash", "16/02/2017"},
                    {"2", "33,1", "shop", "cash", "15/01/2020"},
                    {"3", "17,3", "gym", "visa", "10/01/2016"},
                    {null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null, null},   };
```

So I tried using `Arrays.sort()` using the `Comparator` but I can't seem to get it right since I got those nulls inside I always get `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

What I tried is this:

```
Arrays.sort(array, (String[] o1, String[] o2) -> Float.compare(Float.parseFloat(o2[1]), 
                        Float.parseFloat(o1[1])));
```

And what I'm trying to get is:

```
                {"1", "44,4", "shop", "cash", "16/02/2017"},
                {"2", "33,1", "shop", "cash", "15/01/2020"},
                {"5", "22,2", "car payment", "visa", "21/04/2016"},
                {"3", "17,3", "gym", "visa", "10/01/2016"}};
```

Any help would be so appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I bet the problem is in your comparator code. If, for instance, you are sorting the array on `Entry`, then you can always choose the Entry `null` to come after a non-null one.

Comment: Sorry for not being made understood. I just edited the question.

Comment: Also, you can always _filter_ the string arrays that you think are invalid. That way you have non-null values for the fields that you care about (in sorting).

Comment: Yes, I also think my problem are the nulls inside but I don't know how to make them disappear, neither make Arrays.sort work cause of them.

Comment: Can you give me a code example to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following code works reasonably well:

```
public class StringArraySorter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String array[][]={  {"5", "22,2", "car payment", "visa", "21/04/2016"},
                {"1", "44,4", "shop", "cash", "16/02/2017"},
                {"2", "33,1", "shop", "cash", "15/01/2020"},
                {"3", "17,3", "gym", "visa", "10/01/2016"},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
        };

        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                String a1 = o1[1]; // amount field
                String a2 = o2[1]; // amount field
                if (a1 != null && a2 != null) {
                    a1 = a1.replace(',', '.');
                    a2 = a2.replace(',', '.');
                    return Float.compare(Float.parseFloat(a2), Float.parseFloat(a1));
                }
                return 1; // non-null value for amount takes precedence, whatever that may be
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }
}
```

It prints (modified to insert newlines) which is close to your requirements:

```
[[1, 44,4, shop, cash, 16/02/2017], 
[2, 33,1, shop, cash, 15/01/2020], 
[5, 22,2, car payment, visa, 21/04/2016], 
[3, 17,3, gym, visa, 10/01/2016], 
[null, null, null, null, null], 
[null, null, null, null, null], 
[null, null, null, null, null], 
[null, null, null, null, null]]
```

Now, you could always *prune* your input array to remove the records (string arrays) that have certain key fields `null` (or invalid in some other way), before sending the array to the `Arrays.sort` method. An initial attempt at it using Java 8 constructs (but arguably, a bit cryptic) would be:

```
Arrays.stream(array).filter(a -> a[2] != null)
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> Float.compare(Float.parseFloat(o1[1].replace(',', '.')), Float.parseFloat(o1[1].replace(',', '.'))))
            .forEach(a -> System.out.println("{" + Arrays.stream(a).map(s -> "\"" + s + "\"").collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) +
            "}"));
```

that prints:

```
{"1", "44,4", "shop", "cash", "16/02/2017"}
{"2", "33,1", "shop", "cash", "15/01/2020"}
{"5", "22,2", "car payment", "visa", "21/04/2016"}
{"3", "17,3", "gym", "visa", "10/01/2016"}
```

Comment: It works smooooooth!
But how can I print it formatted like that? Can I use printf or should I use a for each?

Comment: Yeah, for printing it the way you want it, perhaps you can iterate through the array and use your custom _stringifier_.